# Making anaglyph of DEM in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, orfeo-toolbox

I want to know how to make an anaglyph of a DEM using QGIS. I've been trying with Orfeo Toolbox but I couldn't.

Can I make anaglyphs with other toolbox or plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any tools / plugins in QGIS but I think current standalone QGIS is installed with SAGA 2.3.2 (GUI).

From SAGA's 3D view mode:

[image]

You can start anaglyph view.

[image]